# Is there a good Perl project plugin for Eclipse Galileo or NetBeans 6.7?

Tags: perl, netbeans6.7, eclipse-3.5

I tried to use [Perl Editor and IDE for Eclipse](http://www.epic-ide.org/), but I get failures on installation, and I haven't found anything for NetBeans other than a syntax highlighter (no way to execute or debug Perl from within the IDE and no way to make a Perl project).

The error that I get when installing the Perl Editor and IDE for Eclipse is:

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
  session context was:(profile=epp.package.java, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
  No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.ant.ui,3.4.1.v20090901_r351
  No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.cvs,1.0.300.v200909170800
  No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jdt,3.5.1.v200909170800
  No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jdt.apt.core,3.3.201.R35x_v20090818-0235
  No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jdt.apt.pluggable.core,1.0.201.R35x_v20090818-0225
  No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jdt.compiler.apt,1.0.201.R35x_v20090825-1530
  No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jdt.compiler.tool,1.0.100.v_972_R35x
  No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jdt.core,3.5.1.v_972_R35x
  No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jdt.debug.ui,3.4.1.v20090811_r351
  No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user,3.5.1.r351_v20090821-0800
  No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jdt.junit,3.5.1.r351_v20090708-0800
  No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jdt.ui,3.5.1.r351_v20090821-0800
  No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.pde.build,3.5.1.R35x_20090820
  No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.pde.core,3.5.100.v20090821
  No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.team.cvs.ui,3.3.201.R35x_v20090826-0905
  No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.ui.views.log,1.0.100.v20090731
  No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.junit4,4.5.0.v20090824
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.cvs,1.1.101.R35x_v20090811-7E79FEd9KKF5H2YDWFLLBL01A16
  No repository found containing: binary,org.eclipse.cvs_root,1.1.101.R35x_v20090811-7E79FEd9KKF5H2YDWFLLBL01A16
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.jdt,3.5.1.r351_v20090810-0600-7r88FEoFI0WTo6Az-1qFRHm37ChJ
  No repository found containing: binary,org.eclipse.jdt_root,3.5.1.r351_v20090810-0600-7r88FEoFI0WTo6Az-1qFRHm37ChJ
```

Is there anything out there?

Comment: Just a note, there appearers to be some issues with the eclipse update today, but that is regarding the core application. It may update / install correctly tomorrow, at least I'm hoping so!

Answer (score 3):

If you write Perl, use an IDE written in Perl -> [Padre](http://padre.perlide.org/) .
As an alternative , you can use Vim or emacs.

P.S. : never tried to write Perl with Eclipse

Comment: I don't want a text editor. I specifically asked for IDE integration with Eclipse or IDE so I can have code completion, debugger integration, etc. If I wanted a text editor, I would just use Notepad++, which I already have.

Comment: Cool, instead of losing so much time to configure your IDE for a language that really doesn't need an IDE at all.. I would spend that time on more valuable things such as writing code which is the fun part of programming :)

Comment: I am currently using a text editor, and it's a pain. I don't like to write code without syntax checking, debugger integration, code completion, and version control (in my case, ClearCase) integration. Anyone that doesn't use an IDE is, in my opinion, wasting time.

Comment: ok, then stop using an IDE made for Java and start using an IDE made for Perl at least , which is the beforementioned [Padre](http://padre.perlide.org/).

Comment: @Thomas: I guess that I am just wasting time, then. I think most of your belief comes from the fact that you think most of a programmers job is typing. If that's the case, I think that's why you're wasting time. Most of my job is thinking, then a little typing. That thinking part saves a lot of that typing part. :)

Comment: "If you write Perl, use an IDE written in Perl" -> that sounds more hardcore than an Emacs user. Also, loonier. There is definitely something to be said for using an editor written by people who understand the target language. But this sort of absolutism? leads to "if you write French, use an editor written in French." Hey, I like how Emacs is extensible via elisp -- but I'm glad that the core is written in C.

Comment: Who was it that said "learn one editor, and learn it well" ? You shouldn't have to switch editors for each language.

Comment: @OtherMichael I don't use Padre myself, actually I don't think one should depend on the IDE for anything, actually you shouldn't depend on the language or the OS or the hardware, or the wires, or the keyboard. The best thing is to take your computer and throw it away and use juse pen and paper.That is the one true IDE(and the only one). But since the initial poster was so concerned with the language he writes and the IDE "Anyone that doesn't use an IDE is, in my opinion, wasting time." , I though that it would be best to suggest a specialised IDE for Perl, and the only one is Padre.

Comment: >"Anyone that doesn't use an IDE is, in my opinion, wasting time." -- yeah, that was a bit of an extremist statement. I use Emacs primarily, with excursions into Visual Studio and Eclipse when necessary.

Answer (score 1):

If you want an IDE with code completion, debugger integration, etc, take a close look at Komodo, from ActiveState. There are [free](https://www.activestate.com/products/komodo-edit/) and [professional editions](https://www.activestate.com/products/komodo-edit/), and is available for OS X, Linux, and Windows.

It has excellent integrated debugging capabilities, code completion, code-folding, and much much more. It is the best Perl IDE I have used, without question. The pro version is well worth the money.

Comment: Looks good, and if I get into Perl more on my own, I might consider it. But I don't think work will buy it for me...sadly.

Comment: Well, I've faced a similar situation where I wanted a tool my employer wouldn't purchase. You simply need to quantify it for them. Komodo costs $245. For the sake of argument, let's assume that your time costs them $30 per hour. 245/30 = 8.16 hours. 

If you can argue that it will save you 8 hours (1 business day) worth of time, then the tool is essentially free. Your time does cost them money. Similarly, becoming more efficient and productive also *saves* them money.

Answer (score 1):

From my recent experience, I would suggest giving the EPIC installation another shot. Not only is EPIC free, but I believe it's more capable than Komodo at the moment. The Komodo forums are full of people complaining about the Perl integration, which makes sense given that Komodo tries to meet the needs of many different languages.

EPIC, on the other hand, feels like a native Perl IDE (if there ever was one). Local debugging, remote debugging, a helpful RegEx tool, Perl::Critic and Perltidy integration, and -- the feature I use most -- a built-in Perldoc viewer (and all of the other things you'd expect, e.g.: code completion, code folding, syntax highlighting, etc.). Combine that with the Remote System Explorer (RSE), a SCM plugin (Git, Subversion, etc.), and the Mylyn (task-focused interface) plugin and you've got yourself one heck of a development toolkit.

The Padre project, to be sure, is one to watch and try for Perl development. But, for the moment -- having just gone through a major tools upgrade myself -- I can't recommend EPIC enough. It just works.

Answer (score 0):

I tried Epic install today myself and got the errors that you are getting.  Both the stable and the testing repos produce the stacktrace you show.

CentOS5.3
Galileo
Eclipse for PHP Developers
Build id: 20090619-0625

TomL